# Backup Exec 11D and MS WSS 3.0 Granlar Restore?

Tags: restore, wss-3.0, backupexec

Has anyone use the Backup Exec 11D  (7170 SP4) with the Share Point Agent to backup and restore?

I have been using the Agent to back a WSS 3.0 SP2 and the backups are reporting successful.  I have the granular option set.  I can see individual files with no issue.

Though when I have tried to run a granular restore of a few files with-in share point it does not restore the files.
I have also tried to use the rediretion of files to a flat file on another server.  The direcctory tree is created but no files are restored.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are the files you want to restore actually in the backup set you're restoring from? What type of backup? Full, Differential, Incremental, Copy?

Comment: Yes the files are in the backup set, and it is from a full backup.

Answer (score 1):

I had ended up talking with the Backup Exec support.

Log story short, the Granular restore is (for lack of better words) quirky.  The tech said it got better in version 12 and above.

So closing this as I could not get the granular restore to go with their help.